# Porting C# code. Is this a reference to a global object?

Tags: c#, physics-engine, farseer

I'm trying to port the [Aether.Physics2D](https://github.com/tainicom/Aether.Physics2D) library from C# to Xojo. This is essentially a tweaked version of the Farseer physics engine. It's mostly done but there's one part of the source code that I can't work out (it may be because C# is not my main language).

In [Dynamics/Contacts/Contact.cs](https://github.com/tainicom/Aether.Physics2D/blob/master/Physics2D/Dynamics/Contacts/Contact.cs) there are multiple references to what looks like a global Collision object but I can't find it's definition. For instance, **on line 405**, in the `switch`:

```cs
case ContactType.Polygon:
  Collision.Collision.CollidePolygons(ref manifold, (PolygonShape)FixtureA.Shape, ref transformA, (PolygonShape)FixtureB.Shape, ref transformB);
  break;
```

I have already ported the `Collision` class and its `CollidePolygons` static method (defined [here](https://github.com/tainicom/Aether.Physics2D/blob/master/Physics2D/Collision/Collision.cs)) but why is this code not just:

```cs
Collision.CollidePolygons(ref manifold, (PolygonShape)FixtureA.Shape, ref transformA, (PolygonShape)FixtureB.Shape, ref transformB);
```

Instead of:

```cs
Collision.Collision.CollidePolygons(ref manifold, (PolygonShape)FixtureA.Shape, ref transformA, (PolygonShape)FixtureB.Shape, ref transformB);
```

Essentially, why are there **two** `Collision` calls?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please give a reference to the declaration of `Collision`.

Comment: https://github.com/tainicom/Aether.Physics2D/blob/master/Physics2D/Collision/Collision.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's just because it's a class called `Collision` within a namespace called `Collision`:

```
namespace tainicom.Aether.Physics2D.Collision
{
    public static class Collision
    {
    }
}
```

If you're porting the code anyway, I'd strongly recommend that you [fix this mistake](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one/).

You could also change the calling code with a `using` directive:

```
using Collision = tainicom.Aether.Physics2D.Collision.Collision;
...
// Calling the method is simpler now
Collision.CollidePolygons(...);
```

You might want to provide your alias with a different name, actually:

```
// TODO: Think of a better name to use :)
using CollisionClass = tainicom.Aether.Physics2D.Collision.Collision;
...
CollisionClass.CollidePolygons(...);
```

That way the name `Collision` doesn't change its meaning at all, but you don't need to use `Collision.Collision` anywhere.